# Possible to add default value for a created registry key but do not allow that value to reset on Repair (without custom CA code)?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I am trying to to add default value for a created registry key **EDIT: (HKLM)** but without allowing that value to reset on Repair, and ideally without having to write any code (I think this is something Windows Installer would have in its toolset)

Here is my solution so far:

1. Added Component which is in charge of adding (or removing) the registry key. The 'data' for this is simply the name of a property `[MYPROPERTY]`
2. Added a Property called `MYPROPERTY`, this has a value of 1 in the table. It can be changed to 0 by the installing user at the command line.
3. I added a `SetProperty` CA for `MYPROPERTY` with a Condition so that it only runs on first Install and not on things like Repair.

The problem I believe is that I have a value of 1 hardcoded for the `MYPROPERTY` value in the Property table. Obviously, a Repair will reset it to 1. **My question  is if there is an alternative way to be looking at this problem**. Otherwise, I believe I would have to write custom CA to cache the original value and then restore it after Repair. I guess I am trying to figure out ways of doing things with native Windows Installer instead of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did, in case this is useful:

1. Created a Property who's value was the default value for the registry setting
2. Created an AppSearch to look for the value in the registry and store that in a separate property
3. Created a SetProperty CA to get the property value which was set by the AppSearch above, and assign its value to the property created in step 1. Then, apply an 'only on repair' condition such as `REINSTALL~="ALL"`

This way if the user changed the value to something other than default, it is restored

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to set a value and then just leave it. You can do this by setting a blank GUID for the component installing the key, but I don't like this solution.

I would instead update your application to write the default key itself on first start. The application can then update the key as it sees fit - provided the key is stored in HKCU so that the key is writable.

Generally all HKCU data should be written by the application.exe. HKLM data should be written by the setup and kept to a minimum.

Comment: +1 for GUID mention, even though I probably won't use that as I recently ran into issues where newer installers were violating Component rules and a fix was to generate new GUID for the components which were not being removed/re-installed. Scary stuff.

Comment: This needs to write to HKLM.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is to search for the property with a MSI registry search when the setup starts, whether a fresh install or a repair. Then the property is either overwritten by the dialog, or keeps the value that was already in the registry, so the repair rewrites the correct value. I see no reason to have a default value in the Property table.

Comment: An alternative to keeping default value in Property table would be what, another Custom Action to write the default value to the property?